# TFS 2017 and custom control area

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, plugins

With your help, as well as with the help of [manual](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/custom-control) I wrote a combobox control for the work items. I set the height (100px for exmpl) of the control in the file **vss-extension.json** (contributions -> properties -> height). It looks like this:
https://gyazo.com/3490e0ed2ce93c2710df1689c108cbf4
but when i opened dropdown list of combobox is displayed only in the area of the my control:
https://gyazo.com/a9c1ae6f8ecc9965f37ce677aa69956a
I can set the height of the control so large that the dropdown list will be seen completely, but it looks so crooked
https://gyazo.com/5723d1ae0a8362cc77bcd36d1be3962f

Judging by the html, this is due to the fact that my control is placed as a separate html-document inside the frame.

how to make my control to open the drop-down list on top of other fields?

Comment: A similar problem:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/11a77e10-233e-43b4-87b1-06a589c8a3c5/using-combo-control-inside-workitemfromcontrol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drop list should be dynamically base on your needs. If you hard code the height, when you add some values in the drop list, it will not expand correctly and be cropped out.

You could try to use via [resize()](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/core-sdk#method_resize) method in Core SDK.

> If you want to dynamically resize the iframe, you can use the resize
>   method available in the client SDK.

First, remove the `"height": 100px,` section from the contribution preperties.

And then, call the resize() method . For example, resize the width to 100 and height to 200:

```
VSS.resize(100,200);
```

Comment: Your option changes the size of the control, essentially doing what is shown in the screenshot https://gyazo.com/5723d1ae0a8362cc77bcd36d1be3962f  But I would like to have my dropdown list open just like the standard dropdown list (opening over other controls).  Is this possible?

Comment: In any case, this method does not work and does not change the size of the iframe.

Comment: @krabcore To answer your question in the first comment: No, this is not possible. Unfortunately this is in the nature of IFRAMEs.